# Zend\Module missing when trying to install ZendDeveloperTools module

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I am trying to install the [`ZF2` module](http://modules.zendframework.com/) called [`ZendDeveloperTools`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) for use with `ZF2 beta4`. I have placed the module inside my `Module` directory and added it to the `modules` array in `config/application.config.php`. When I load my app, I get the below error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Module\Consumer\AutoloaderProvider' not
>   found in /.../module/ZendDeveloperTools/Module.php on line 29

Looking at `Module.php`, here is the list of libraries that the module is trying to use:

```
use Zend\Module\Manager,
    Zend\Module\Consumer\AutoloaderProvider,
    Zend\EventManager\StaticEventManager;
```

When I look at the latest version of the [`ZF2` library](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend) which I have installed, I can see that the whole `Zend\Module` path is missing (`Zend\EventManager` is there).

Also, I can see what the [`ZendDeveloperTools`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) module was last updated 4 months ago whereas [`ZF2` came out about 1 month ago](http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog/entry/Zend-Framework-2-0-0beta4-Released).

**Can I use the `ZendDeveloperTools` module at all (if so what do I need to adapt), or do I need to wait for a refactor of the module matching `ZF2` beta 4?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the last person to work on ZendDeveloperTools. Zend Framework 2 is still in beta (we're about to release beta5 next week, after which ZF2 will go into RC). ZendDeveloperTools has not been updated since sometime around beta1, *maybe* beta2. At that time, the only thing it did was very rough and basic execution time profiling using microtime(), and it had a method for prepending some output (the execution time) before the  tag, and immediately prior the response was sent to the browser. That was really just a proof of concept for what we really want it to be.

To answer your question, this module is very much out of date, and simply will not work with the most recent beta4 release (nor the current master branch on Github). Way too much has changed, including changed namespaces (Zend\Module is not Zend\ModuleManager) and the entire MVC stack being refactored. The module simply needs to be majorly updated. Luckily, at least one person has started on some updates [here](https://github.com/coss/ZendDeveloperTools/tree/redux/sf-profiler-alike), and one of my developers as well as myself will be working with him on his updates to try to get ZendDeveloper tools functional and doing what we have envisioned. I'm also going to reach out to the developer behind the [ZFDebug](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug) project for ZF1 to see if he's interested in helping.

The idea is this:

By default, ZendDeveloperTools should provide a nice floating toolbar on non-ajax HTTP requests (probably only those with a  tag). This will be similar to [Symfony2's web debug toolbar](http://symfony.com/blog/towards-symfony-2-1-the-new-web-debug-toolbar) or the [ZFDebug](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug) project for ZF1.

It will be designed with ZF2 modules in mind so that in addition to whatever default debugging tools we provide in the bar, third-party modules can provide their own "plugins" / data providers, to be displayed as additional buttons/menus on the toolbar. For example, one of my developers has started on a [profiler module](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler) (currently provides DB profiling but will allow setting arbitrary timers as well), which we'd like to eventually have provide data to the ZendDeveleperTools toolbar.

---

Update Jul 6 2012: I've updated the latest master of ZendDeveloperTools with the great work done by [@coss](https://github.com/coss) on GitHub. It should now be functional with beta5 which was released just a few minutes ago. :) It looks pretty nice, too!